# how to make a scatter with regression line graph in amcharts / highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, amcharts

I read all amcharts and highcharts demo and cant figure out how to draw chart like

[image]

The issue I am having is the X axis is text, not numeric like most amcharts/highcharts demos are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter that you have categories on the x axis, as far as the scatter plot is concerned - your x values are the array index of the categories (0-5 in the case of your image).

There is a plugin to auto calculate a regression line, here:

- http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/22/Highcharts%20regression

Or, you can calculate your own and plot it normally.

However, a regression line through a group of categories doesn't make much sense.  I don't see how it can tell you anything useful, and is probably more likely to cause confusion or outright misunderstanding.

This seems to me to be data that would be more appropriate to plot with a bar chart than a scatter plot.

FWIW

**{{edit:**

After looking at this longer, I am somewhat unclear: is that actually a regression line, or is that an average, or a target...?

If that's the case, you can either plot it is a line series, or you can use plotLines:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines

Example with a `plotLine`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/63/

Comment: my boss wants me to draw the chart so he must have a good reason to have that chart. I called it "regression" because most chart similar to that have "regression" in the title. It is more than a base line to me. But I will check out your links and hopefully come up with something similar to what my boss needs. I think your plotLine example is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks very much

Comment: If the line is an average or a target, then it makes perfect sense to make the chart this way, and it works equally well as a bar chart or a dot plot. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

The chart like this is very easily done using amCharts regular [Serial chart](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart) with line graph with bullets ([`bullet: "diamond"`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#bullet)) and no line ([`lineAlpha: 0`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#lineAlpha)).

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "category": "Civil",
    "value": 0.87
  }, {
    "category": "Piping",
    "value": 1.1
  }, {
    "category": "Mechanical",
    "value": 0.69
  }, {
    "category": "Electrical",
    "value": 0.82
  }, {
    "category": "Insulation",
    "value": 1.42
  }, {
    "category": "Completion",
    "value": 1.1
  } ],
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "guides": [{
      "value": 1,
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "lineColor": "#f00"
    }]
  } ],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [ {
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "bullet": "diamond",
    "valueField": "value",
    "lineColor": "#5782bf"
  } ],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "category",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickPosition": "start"
  }

} );
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 600px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: nicely done, I am sorry that I can not mark your answer as accepted because jlbriggs had solved the question with Highcharts. Thank yo uvery much for helping me and amcharts community.

Comment: No worries. I just wanted to add this answer so the question was answered in full.